# Sort list using STL sort function

Tags: c++, list, stl, sorting

I'm trying to sort a list (part of a class) in descending order containing items of a `struct`, but it doesn't compile:

> error: no match for 'operator-' in '__last - __first'

```
sort(Result.poly.begin(), Result.poly.end(), SortDescending());
```

And here's `SortDescending`:

```
struct SortDescending
{
    bool operator()(const term& t1, const term& t2)
    { 
        return t2.pow < t1.pow; 
    }
};
```

Can anyone tell me what's wrong?

Comment: @Glen see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2425452/polynomial-operations-using-operator-overloading

Answer (score 44, accepted):

The standard algorithm `std::sort` requires random access iterators, which `std::list<>::iterator`s are not (list iterators are bidirectional iterators).

You should use the `std::list<>::sort` member function.

Comment: but i don't know how to overload correctly the less operator for my class

Comment: @Vlad, you don't need to overload anything. `Result.poly.sort(SortDescending());` should work just fine.

Comment: The `operator ()` in your comparer should *still* be marked `const` as it doesn’t modify any members.

Answer (score 10):

`std::list` has a built-in `sort` method that you need to use since `std::sort` only works with random access iterators, whereas `std::list::iterator` merely belongs to the bidirectional iterator class of iterators.

```
Result.poly.sort(SortDescending());
```

Also, your `operator ()` should be marked `const`.

```
struct SortDescending
{
    bool operator()(const term& t1, const term& t2) const
    { 
        return t2.pow < t1.pow; 
    }
};
```

Finally, if the type `term` overloads an appropriate `operator>` you might not need to write your own comparer for sorting — simply use `std::greater<T>` (located in the standard header `<functional>`):

```
Result.poly.sort(std::greater<term>());
```

Comment: No this isn`t it, there's nothing in the standard that says that this needs to be const. If you look at the error message it seems like `operator -` is missing for the input iterators.

Comment: It would make a better answer if it was reordered (const-ness is a side-issue here).

Comment: still doesn't work either with my own comparer or using greater() it still gives a bunch of errors

Comment: @Andreas: my concern was that a temporary object gets passed into the `sort` function. I had forgotten that the comparer is passed by value and since temporaries cannot be bound to non-`const` references this would have required the function to be `const`.

Comment: @Vlad: *what* errors? This code should work. Did you include the header `<functional>` for `std::greater`?

Comment: `std::greater` will only work if `operator>` is overloaded for `term` which probably isn't the case here.

Answer (score 4):

It seems like the iterator types for `Result.poly` is missing `operator -`. `std::sort` doesn't work with `std::list` change to `Result.poly.sort`

Comment: but i don't know how to overload correctly the less operator for my class

Comment: @Vlad you can call this by `Result.poly.sort(SortDescending())`, no need for `operator <`.

Comment: @Konrad I think he was talking about `operator <` and had missed the fact that there's a version of `std::ist::sort` that takes a predicate.