# why only std::list::sort()?

Tags: c++, sorting, stl

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Sort list using stl sort function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2432857/sort-list-using-stl-sort-function)

The C++ standard library gives strict linear sequence container, linear sequence container, associative container.

`std::sort()` is available for all kinds of containers. But why only it provides sort for list. `std::list::sort()`?

Comment: presumably because there can be a more optimal implementation that can utilise implementation details of list - which may not be available to the general sort function

Comment: An explanation is given [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2432857/sort-list-using-stl-sort-function).

Comment: @Nim:  Not really.  See the responses.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

`std::sort` only works on random access containers.  And the only non-random access container in the standard library that it makes sense to sort is `std::list`.

`std::sort` certainly doesn't work on associative containers as you seem to think.  What sense would that make?  Associative containers are accessed by the value of their key, not by position.

As noted by Mike, C++11 also has `std::forward_list`, which, by no accident, also has it's own sort function.

Comment: Also `std::forward_list` these days.

Comment: Also note that the complexity guarantees are different for list sort and standard sort.

Comment: @KerrekSB: as per C++11 both are O(N log N).

Comment: @ybungalobill: Yes, you're right. The key difference is that `std::sort` reassigns elements, while `std::list::sort` moves *nodes* around without touching their values.

Answer (score 7):

`std::sort` only works for random access iterators, but a `std::list` only provides biderectional iterators. Since it therefore cannot be used with `std::sort`, it needs its own implementation, which is also likely to be more optimized for a doubly linked list.

Likewise you cannot use `std::map` or `std::set` iterators with `std::sort`. But for these you don't need it anyway, as they are always sorted.

As a side note, there are also `std::map::find` and the like. These are indeed not required, as you can use all iterators with `std::find`. But the member function versions provide optimized algorithms for the individual containers, which are more efficient than `std::find`'s linear complexity.