# sorting std::lists using std::sort

Tags: c++, list, sorting, std

> **Possible Duplicate:**
> [Sort list using stl sort function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2432857/sort-list-using-stl-sort-function)

My question is can we sort two std::lists using std::sort function? I have 2 string lists

```
  std::list<std::string>list1, list2;
  .....//entering values to list
  std::sort(list1.begin(), list1.end());

  std::sort(list2.begin(), list2.end());
```

while i am sorting these lists i am getting error.
I tried with std::vector, at this time the sort works.

The error is like

> C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\include\xutility(1158) :
> see declaration of 'std::operator -'
> 1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\include\algorithm(3642):
> error C2784: '_Base1::difference_type std::operator -
> (const std::_Revranit<_RanIt,_Base> &,const std::_Revranit<_RanIt2,_Base2> &)' :
> could not deduce template argument for 'const std::_Revranit<_RanIt,_Base> &'
> from 'std::_List_iterator<_Mylist>'
> 1>          with
> 1>          [
> 1>              _Mylist=std::_List_valstd::string,std::allocator<std::string>
> 1>          ]

I have to know that only std::sort supports lists?

Comment: Overload the < operator for your object (if it's not already defined) and use std::sort.

Comment: possible duplicate of [why only std::list::sort()?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7996116/why-only-stdlistsort) and  [Sort list using stl sort function](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2432857/sort-list-using-stl-sort-function)

Comment: @Martol1ni: It's `std::string`.  `operator<` is defined, but it won't help.

Comment: I did not notice, sorry.

Answer (score 60, accepted):

You can't use `std::sort` to sort `std::list`, because `std::sort` requires iterators to be random access, and `std::list` iterators are only bidirectional.

However, `std::list` has a member function `sort` that will sort it:

```
list.sort();
// if you want to use a comparator different from the default one:
// list.sort(comparator);
```

Answer (score 12):

You should use `list::sort`, which may use a different algorithm. `std::sort` requires random-access iterators (supporting jumps of arbitrary size) whereas list iterators can only go forwards or backwards by one link at a time.

See C++11 25.4.1.1:

```
template<class RandomAccessIterator> void sort(RandomAccessIterator first, 
         RandomAccessIterator last);
```

and 23.3.5.5/27 (members of `std::list`):

```
void sort();
template <class Compare> void sort(Compare comp);
```