# what's the difference between list.sort and std::sort?

Tags: c++, algorithm, templates, std

I am trying to compile the following code using clang but got the following error.

I am wondering why using `sort` from the `list` class would work, but not `std::sort`.

```
#include <list>
#include <iostream>

int main(){
    std::string strings[] = {"hello", "nihao", "byebye", "yo"};
    std::list<std::string> cars(strings, strings+sizeof(strings) / sizeof(char **));

    // cars.sort(std::less<std::string>()); // compiles fine and produce a sorted list

    std::sort(cars.rbegin(), cars.rend(), std::less<std::string>() ); // this one won't compile

    for (std::list<std::string>::iterator it = cars.begin(); it != cars.end(); ++it)
        std::cout << *it << " - ";

    std::cout << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

> /usr/include/c++/4.2.1/bits/stl_iterator.h:320:25: error: invalid
>   operands to binary expression ('iterator_type' (aka
>         'std::_List_iterator >') and 'iterator_type')
>       { return __y.base() - __x.base(); }

Comment: possible duplicate of [Sort list using stl sort function](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2432857/sort-list-using-stl-sort-function)

Comment: Mostly that `std::sort` won't work on `std::list`.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

`std::sort` requires *random access* iterators, which `std::list` does not provide. Consequently, `std::list` and `std::forward_list` implement their own member functions for sorting which work with their weaker iterators. <s>The complexity guarantees of those member functions are worse than those of the more efficient general algorithm.</s>[Whoops: see comments.]

Moreover, the member functions can take advantage of the special nature of the list data structure by simply relinking the list nodes, while the standard algorithm has to perform something like `swap` (or something to that effect), which requires object construction, assignment and deletion.

Note that `remove()` is a similar case: The standard algorithm is merely some iterator-returning rearrangement, while the `list` member function performs the lookup and actual removal all in one go; again thanks to being able to take advantage of the knowledge of the list's internal structure.

Comment: The complexity guarantees are not worse. The member functions are "approximately N log N comparisons", whereas the algorithm is "O(N log N) comparisons". This is as you'd expect considering that the member functions are going to use merge sort, and `std::sort` is likely to use some kind of intro-sort, falling back to heapsort.

Comment: @Steve: Ah, indeed, a flat-out misconception on my part. The standard does say though that the list function uses N log N comparisons, while the standard algorithm is "O(N log N)". Same asymptotics, but I suppose the constants are worse for the list version.

Comment: Maybe the constants are worse, but remember that the standard complexity guarantees only care about number of comparisons, whereas one of the major performance factors when comparing merge/quick/heapsorts is locality of reference. So the constants applied to the comparison part of it aren't necessarily the major performance issue. I don't know what the worst-case number of comparisons is for heapsort, whether it's more or less than N log N, but N log N is the worst case for mergesort. And of course the expected case of introsort is overall faster runtime than the expected case of heapsort.

Comment: @SteveJessop: I'd imagine that simply because you need to walk the iterators one by one you'll have a greater overall overhead factor, no matter which specific algorithm -- though perhaps I'm now confusing binary searching with sorting. Maybe the advantage of random access iterators isn't actually that great after all...

Comment: Merge sort also does approximately N log N iterator increment operations (in fact, it does one increment per comparison, for fairly simple reasons), which is fine, although the locality depends entirely on how the list was constructed and vagaries of the allocator. The reason merge sort is so terrific for linked lists is just that it requires no extra memory, whereas merging arrays does. As with any sorting algorithm, to get a feel for it perform it manually on a deck of cards - you don't feel that you're missing random-access iterators :-)

Comment: @SteveJessop: That's a great suggestion, especially since it fits very nicely into an entirely independent problem I was after concerning educational use of a deck of cards! But let me clarify: Is the specialness of `list` implementation in the fact that nodes can be relinked without moving objects? That would be a much more useful explanation!

Comment: Oops, hang on, I'm only thinking of the actual merge, sorry, which does `2*k` increments to merge two blocks of size `k`. There's some extra incrementing needed to divide the data into "halves". And yes, re-linking nodes helps when the elements are large. Observe that *insertion sort*, with a binary search for the insertion point, only requires O(N log N) comparisons, it's the element-copying that's the killer ;-)

Comment: Sorry, in case this is becoming unclear, I mean that insertion sort of an array requires only O(N log N) comparisons, and hence meets the complexity requirement stated in the standard, provided you perversely choose to read it "O(N log N) comparisons plus unspecified additional time", rather than as I think it was intended: "O(N log N) comparisons *is the bounding factor on time*". Insertion sort of a linked list can be weaselled the same way, come to think of it, it's just that binary search on a linked list is clearly a farce...

Comment: @SteveJessop: Well, most notably, you shouldn't get *any* element constructor/destructor calls in the list algorithm, while you should get plenty in the standard algorithm!

Comment: Btw, `swap` doesn't necessarily require *much* object construction, assignment and deletion. You'd hope that for any type we care about, the user has implemented an efficient swap. So normally we're constructing a few temporary pointers and other built-in types, not expensive allocated resources. But that efficiency is of course limited if the size of the object is big.

Comment: @SteveJessop: I just made some tests with my trusted test class that prints out everything that's done to it, and it appears that GCC 4.6.1 doesn't use `swap` during `std::sort` and `std::remove`. It's just move-construct and move-assign everywhere. (And completely silent in `list::sort()`, and destruction only in `list::remove()`.)

Comment: @TomalakGeret'kal: thanks :-) And no complaints about semicolon abuse?

Comment: @KerrekSB: No abuse detected in your answer (though I didn't check the comments yet!)

Comment: @TomalakGeret'kal: It'd be in the question, final sentence -- I'm happy I pass your muster :-) Bedtime now!

Comment: @KerrekSB: Oh, god, there it is >.<