# Acclerated C++ : Can I write a program that sorts either a list or a vector using the same command?

Tags: c++

I realize that the std::sort function requires use of random access iterators, and lists have bidirectional iterators.  There is a question regarding this at :

[Sort list using STL sort function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2432857/sort-list-using-stl-sort-function)

I am working to answer question 5-4 in the Accelerated C++ book for home study purposes.

> 5-4. Look again at the driver functions you wrote in the previous exercise. Note that it is possible to write a driver that only differs in the declaration of the type for the data structure that holds the input file. If your vector and list test drivers differ in any other way, rewrite them so that they differ only in this declaration.

Besides this textbook question, this would be useful if I used templates instead of typedef to define a container type.

(Be aware this could happen to you by the pronoun censors: https://www.theregister.co.uk/2019/10/08/stack_overflow_apology/)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> ...sorts either a list or a vector using the same command?

The easiest way is to use overloading:

```
template <typename T>
inline void sort(std::vector<T>& x) { std::sort(x.begin(), x.end()); }

template <typename T>
inline void sort(std::list<T>& x) { x.sort(); }
```

**UPDATE**

You imply that your text hasn't introduced templates yet, so here's a template-free alternative.  The question says *"only differs in the declaration of the type for the data structure that holds the input file"* and we're talking about `vector` and `list`, so there must be something like:

```
std::vector<std::string> input;
```

Maybe the type isn't `std::string` - you might have your own data type - but whatever it is, Standard containers - including `vector` and `list` - have a `typedef` so that the contained type can be refered to a la `decltype<input>::value_type`.  This means you can write more restrictive versions of the templates that only work for `vector`s and `list`s with that specific value type:

```
inline void sort(std::vector<decltype<input>::value_type>& x) { std::sort(x.begin(), x.end()); }

inline void sort(std::list<decltype<input>::value_type>& x) { x.sort(); }
```

Of course, if you want to just hardcode `std::string` or whatever the value type currently is that'll work fine too - only issue from a maintenance perspective is that you'll need to change this code if you change the value type later.

```
inline void sort(std::vector<std::string>& x) { std::sort(x.begin(), x.end()); }

inline void sort(std::list<std::string>& x) { x.sort(); }
```

Comment: Thank you. Both of these answers using templates cover material that only begins to be covered three chapters later. I found one possible way without templates ... using typeid to find the container type followed by IF ELSE logic. Granted, typeid isn't covered in the book yet either.

Comment: @yellowjacket05: I added a template-free alternative that might be what they expect at that stage in the book...?  Cheers.

Comment: Thank you Tony. That's true - I could redefine the function 'sort' and overload it to work with different container types.

Comment: `input` cannot be used before `::`, nor do the standard containers have a member type called `element_type`.

Answer (score 5):

Since the easy way has been answered, let me point out the hard way :

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <iterator>
#include <list>
#include <vector>

template <typename IterType>
struct sort
{
    template<typename Cont, typename Comp>
    inline static void impl(Cont &container, Comp F) {
        container.sort(F);
    }
    template<typename Cont>
    inline static void impl(Cont &container) {
        container.sort();
    }
};

template <>
struct sort<std::random_access_iterator_tag>
{
    template<typename Cont, typename Comp>
    inline static void impl(Cont &container, Comp F) {
        std::sort(std::begin(container), std::end(container), F);
    }
    template<typename Cont>
    inline static void impl(Cont &container) {
        std::sort(std::begin(container), std::end(container));
    }
};

template<typename Cont>
void Sort(Cont &container) {
    sort<typename std::iterator_traits<typename Cont::iterator
        >::iterator_category>::impl(container);
}

template<typename Cont, typename Comp>
void Sort(Cont &container, Comp F) {
    sort<typename std::iterator_traits<typename Cont::iterator
        >::iterator_category>::impl(container, F);
}

int main ()
{
    std::list<int> ml;
    std::vector<int> mv;

    Sort(ml);
    Sort(mv);
    Sort(ml, [](int a, int b) { return a > b; });
    Sort(mv, [](int a, int b) { return a > b; });

    return 0;
}
```

Now, if you only want to distinguish between a `list` and a `vector` the above would be an overkill. Use only if you need to implement a tag dispatchment by type mechanism that would **scale to arbitrary containers that implement certain iterator concepts**.

This way eg sorting an `std::array` or an `std::deque` would not require an extra overload, since their iterators can point to the correct dispatchment structure

Comment: Thank you. A great generic implementation to solve this problem.