# STL sort by multiple parameters C++

Tags: c++, sorting, c++11, stl

I have a list with objects Studenti which are defined with multiple parameters.
I want to sort this list of Students, first by their mean and if means are the same I sort them alphabetically.

In my class Student I declared this header function:
`bool mediaDescrescator(const&, const&);`
Which is implemented in this way:

```
bool Studenti::mediaDescrescator(const Studenti& a, const Studenti& b)
{
    if(a.medie_ != b.medie_)
    {
        return (a.medie_ > b.medie_);
    }

    return (a.nume_ > b.nume_);
}
```

`medie_` is a double private member of Studenti
`nume_` is a std::string private member of Studenti

In main I have a list of Studenti:
`std::list<Studenti> listaStud_ = {stud1, stud2, stud3, stud4, stud5};`

Function call:
`std::sort(listaStud_.begin(), listaStud_.end(), mediaDescrescator);`

My error is: mediaDescrescator was not declared in this scope.

I've seen other topics about this type of sort and they are declared like mine, I tried even with vector type instead of list.
`mediaDescrescator` is called without (), because it must be passed as a function pointer or function object.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`mediaDescrescator` is a member function of `Studenti`. It's defined withing the lexical scope of the class. So you can access `Studenti::mediaDescrescator`, but not `mediaDescrescator`. There is no function named `mediaDescrescator` in the global namespace.

Also, to ward off the next error you may face, be sure it is a `static` member function. You don't need a valid instance to call it, after all. It doesn't access any member variables of `this`.

Answer (score 5):

1. `std::tie` returns a `std::tuple` of references.
2. `std::tuple` defines comparison operators which perform correct lexicographical comparisons.

So all you need to do is turn `Studenti` into a `tuple` with `tie` - then compare the tuples.

```
bool Studenti::mediaDescrescator(const Studenti& a, const Studenti& b)
{
    return std::tie(a.medie_, a.nume_) > std::tie(b.medie_, b.nume_);
}
```

You may find it useful to provide a method called `as_tuple()` on classes that you write:

```
struct Studenti
{
   // rest of class

   auto as_tuple() const { return std::tie(medie_, nume_); }
};
```

Answer (score 2):

There are several problems with your implementation. The first, and the one that your compiler complains about is that `mediaDescrescator` is defined in the scope of `Studenti` and you try to access it in the global scope, use `Studenti::mediaDescrescator` to get a pointer to it. Second, `mediaDescrescator` is a normal member function of `Studenti` and as such it will need to be called on an object. This can be fixed, e.g. by making it a static member function instead, or by making it take one parameter and compare against the current object. Third, the `std::sort` function can not be applied to an `std::list` as it needs random-access iterators and `std::list` only provides bidirectional iterators.

Comment: You where right with the list. I've seen this in other topic. But I must use list type, how can I apply this type of sort without making a copy on a vector type?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/2432946/104774 says use `std::list<>::sort()`

Answer (score 1):

Change function declaration to:

```
bool mediaDescrescator(const Studenti& a, const Studenti& b)
```

Basically have it outside the class.

If you don't want to make the members public, write getter functions for them and use them instead inside the sort.

Comment: It is a good practice to define functions outside the class in order to do stuff on class objects, even with get and set?

Comment: If you use the sort function only once, I would suggest writing a lambda function only in that place. Best practice is to have as much as possible self contained in the class, but sometimes it's not worth the time.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, if `mediaDescrescator()` is a non-static member function, it only needs one "other" parameter because it can work the `this` member.

Secondly, lambdas are easy to have algorithms work with member functions (not tested):

```
listaStud_.sort([](const studenti& a, const studenti& b) { return a.mediaDescrescator(b); });
```

You could also implement the order function directly in the lambda as combined with Richard Hodges' answer (in this case with public members):

```
listaStud_.sort([](const studenti& a, const studenti& b) { return std::tie(a.medie_, a.nume_) > std::tie(b.medie_, b.nume_); });
```

Based on Johan's answer: `std::sort` can't be used on `std::list`, use `std::list<>::sort()` instead as in my code snippets.